# Jedi-vim: No auto-complete on dot (.), testing shows erroneous "no python" error

Tags: jedi-vim

I just installed jedi-vim and supertab (because I already had something bound to `<C-Space>`).  `<Tab>` now shows the autocomplete menu and it's working pretty well, however I don't see any menus when I hit `.`.

If I use `<Tab>` in insert mode after pressing `.`, I get the normal menu that doesn't have the context of the name preceding the dot (and it's not at all useful because of it).

`:verbose imap .` says `No mapping found`, but I'm guessing that's not how jedi-vim works.

---

In my effort to troubleshoot the issue I've disabled my other plugins and replaced my .vimrc with just `execute pathogen#infect()`.

Now, when I `:e foo.py` I see: `"Error: jedi-vim failed to initialize Python: jedi-vim requires Vim with support for Python 2 or 3."`  I didn't get this error before, and :version shows that I have both Python 2 and 3 support.

Scriptnames: https://gist.github.com/hovissimo/a2413d6a5d0e1be356c0

:version: https://gist.github.com/hovissimo/f5a0e630edac8756397e

Edit:
:JediDebugInfo says `Using Python Version: null`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I didn't see the error before, but it looks like my python3 integration in Vim was in fact broken.

I had Python 3.5 32-bit installed, but I was using a 64-bit version of Vim.  Installing a 32-bit version of Vim (making sure it was compiled for python35) seems to have fixed all problems.